# What is a wrapper in Python?

Tags: python, keras, wrapper

I am currently in the process of learning Keras, a Deep Learning module.

I came across a sentence that I can't understand because I don't know what a python Wrapper is.

```
from keras.models import Sequential

#Create the Sequential model
model = Sequential()
```

"The keras.models.Sequential class is a wrapper for the neural network model that treats the network as a sequence of layers. It implements the Keras model interface with common methods like compile(), fit(), and evaluate() that are used to train and run the model."

In the above sentence, what is a Python wrapper and what does it do?

Comment: [wrappers](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/54886/wrapper) are a general software design concept in which an extra function/method/class is created to abstract away some implementation details and provide a cleaner interface to the client.

Answer (score 0):

This is not unique to Python. In this case, `Sequential` is a helper class that provides methods to make the creation of this specific type of neural network model easier. It inherits many properties from its parent class, which is a generic `Model`. See the [source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/engine/sequential.py#L24) for more info.